# Can I prevent running javascript as input on my php website using mysqli_prepare()

Tags: php, prepared-statement, sql-injection

I am using mysql_prepare() function to avoid SQL injection on my website.
and I was wondered that if it is working!!

when I use `<script>alert("something")</script>` as an input of one of the fields, the script goes to my database, and I was wondered if it is normal !?!

Am I missing something?

or the prepare function just avoid SQL injection.

Comment: Neither PHP nor MySQL understands JavaScript. This is just a piece of text. Why wouldn't it appear in your database?

Comment: Oh I figured it out I should use mysqli_real_escape_string() too, to avoid that javascript !!

Comment: _“he script goes to my database, and I was wondered if it is normal !?!”_ - that databases store text, the same way it was entered? Yes, that is pretty normal. Actually, it is basically a _requirement_ for any kind of properly working system. You _want_ to store the actual data, and not any mutilated version of it. Preventing XSS has _nothing_ whatsoever with the data storage, and everything with how you handle it, when you _output_ it into an HTML context.

Comment: because when I load that javascript from my data base it runs and give me the alert but with mysqli_real_escape_string() it doesn't happen anymore.

Comment: _“I should use user mysqli_real_escape_string() too, to avoid that javascript !!”_ - nope, absolutely wrong. You need to handle data according to the rules of the specific context you are inserting it into, _when_ you are inserting it into that context. The context here is MySQL/the database, and not HTML.

Comment: The script executes on output because you're sending it to something that understands JavaScript. You need to encode it with `htmlspecialchars()` to avoid the browser doing that. This is entirely separate from the way you handled it when posting to the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't prevent the execution of JavaScript on your page by using parameterized queries.

The whole purpose of using parameterized queries is to prevent your SQL from breaking when an unexpected input is provided. When you bind the data separately from the SQL then there is no way that the data could affect the SQL. For example:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'test');
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4'); // always set the charset

$email = '1 or 1=1';
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT user FROM users WHERE email=?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
$stmt->execute();
```

In this example, the email looks like SQL, but it will never be treated as SQL by MySQL server. It is bound separately so MySQL receives it already after parsing the SQL. This helps to prevent SQL injection. **Never escape the data that you bind!**

As you can see prepared statements only protect SQL. They don't protect users from submitting JavaScript or HTML code into your database. You would need to add extra validation rules or simply treat it as any other data.

To prevent JavaScript or HTML or any other data from breaking your site, you need to make sure that you always follow the best practices when it comes to output. You must always format the data correctly.

- For HTML use [`htmlentities()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) or [`htmlspecialchars()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) when outputting the data
- For JavaScript use [`json_encode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)
- For URL use [`http_build_query()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)
- etc.